# How to go back to the "try" code everytime the input is not correct (in Java)?

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

I want the program to retry the "try" part of the code every time the input is incorrect and throws an error(which is solved with an exception).

My code looks like this:

```
try {
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
    enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
```

My "makeHumanMove" function checks, if the number is from 1 to 3.. But if the user inserts a letter, it would throw an error and if it happens, I want the program to ask for another input until the user inserts a correct input.

I've tried while and for loops but I keep messing up. Any ideas?

Comment: "I've tried while and for loops but I keep messing up"... --> keep trying.

Comment: Share some of what you "keep messing up".

Comment: You need to use a loop.  Requires thought, and a little bit of planning.

Answer (score 1):

How's about this code:

```
while (true) {
try {
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
    enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);
    break;
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
}
}
```

Make sure that your `makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);` throws `new Exception()`;

Comment: it just goes to an infinite loop, keeps printing out "incorrect input!"

Comment: It will be easier if you publish the complete code in this case. You issue is not in try-catch block

Comment: @KirillK Snippets can only be used for stuff that directly runs in the browser (JavaScript, dare I say VB?).

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes, I'll take it into account next time.

Comment: But removed downvote before that already... that was too strict.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean value outside, set it to `true` at the end of the `try` block. Then you can test for it using a `while` loop.

```
int enteredNumber;
boolean correctNumber = false;
while (!correctNumber) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
        enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
        makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);
        correctNumber = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
    }
}
```

Note that you should not use exceptions at all to report incorrect input. You should test for incorrect input and abort early. You should also consider if `makeHumanMove` should actually be part of the try/catch block; input validation should not be part of the business logic of your application.

```
final int number;
System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
while (true) {
    int enteredNumber;
        try {
            enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Not a number, enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
            userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            continue;
        }
    if (enteredNumber < 1 || enteredNumber > 3) {
        System.out.print("Incorrect number, enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
        continue;
    } else {
        number = enteredNumber;
        break;
    }
}
makeHumanMove(number);
```

Comment: it just goes to an infinite loop.. keeps printing out "incorrect input" and doesn't go back to the try block.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code and entered "g" as the input. This is the result: http://prntscr.com/68i9dd

Comment: Did the last edit (of the second code block) solve your issue?

Comment: It's better now, it doesn't infinitely loop or throw errors, but I can't understand why it asks for user input twice in a row..

Comment: The first time it prints the message "enter the number: " and then you have to insert your input... and when you press enter, it just goes to a next blank line and waits for an input and after you put the input for the second time, the program continues working normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean inputIsCorrect = false;
while(inputIsCorrect == false){
try {
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
    enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);
    inputIsCorrect = true;
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
}
}
```

This, of course, assumes that your makeHumanMove method throws an exception.

If I was doing this, I don't think I would be using exceptions. My code would be more like ...

```
boolean inputIsCorrect = false;
while(inputIsCorrect == false){

    System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
    enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    inputIsCorrect = makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);
}
```

I'd change the makeHumanMove return a value that indicates whether the the inout is valid or not, rather than using exceptions. ( Can't remember if scanner.nextInt() throws exception .... )

Comment: it just goes to an infinite loop, keeps printing out the exception message.

Comment: Have you got `while(inputIsCorrect = false){` rather than `while(inputIsCorrect == false){`